# Why declare a list twice in __init__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reentrancy

I'm reading through the Python Docs, and, under [Section 8.4.1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes),
I found the following `__init__` definition (abbreviated):

```
class ListBasedSet(collections.abc.Set):
    ''' Alternate set implementation favoring space over speed
        and not requiring the set elements to be hashable. '''
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.elements = lst = []
        for value in iterable:
            if value not in lst:
                lst.append(value)
```

The part I don't get is the `self.elements = lst = []` line. Why the double assignment?

Adding some print statements:

```
def __init__(self, iterable):
    self.elements = lst = []
    print('elements id:', id(self.elements))
    print('lst id:', id(lst))
    for value in iterable:
        if value not in lst:
            lst.append(value)
```

Declaring one:

```
ListBasedSet(range(3))
elements id: 4741984136
lst id: 4741984136
Out[36]: <__main__.ListBasedSet at 0x11ab12fd0>
```

As expected, they both point to the same PyObject.

Is brevity the only reason to do something like this? If not, why? Something to do with reentrancy?

Comment: Probably to save on attribute lookup

Comment: There's a cost to attribute lookup?

Comment: python is interpreted. and the address must be calculated: object address + member offset. If you pre-compute the reference as a local variable, you don't have to do this. Nothing is free in this vile world.

Comment: @Ben yes, of course

Comment: I guess I'm surprised that's not cached or something. I'm googling, but is there any resources you could point me to?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: It's not even as simple as "object address + member offset". Instance attributes are stored in a dict, and lookup is a dict lookup.

Comment: @user2357112 that's even worse. It's slow enough with `in` on lists.

Comment: I think an equally probable reason is to save some typing. I'd probably fill the list first and only then assign it to `self` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd call this a case of premature optimization; you don't save *that much* by eliminating the dot, especially for large input iterables; here's some timings:

Eliminating the dot:

```
%timeit ListBasedSet(range(3))
The slowest run took 4.06 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.05 µs per loop

%timeit ListBasedSet(range(30))
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.5 µs per loop

%timeit ListBasedSet(range(3000))
10 loops, best of 3: 119 ms per loop
```

While, with the dot (i.e replace `lst` with `self.elements`:

```
%timeit ListBasedSet(range(3))
The slowest run took 5.97 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.48 µs per loop

%timeit ListBasedSet(range(30))
10000 loops, best of 3: 22.8 µs per loop

%timeit ListBasedSet(range(3000))
10 loops, best of 3: 118 ms per loop
```

As you can see, as we increase the size of the input iterable, the difference in time pretty much disappears, the appending and membership testing pretty much cover any gains.